# Non-nullable instance field '_pages' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got an error in the line 18 List<Map<String, Object>> _pages;

can you help me out?

here are the codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meals_recipes/models/meal.dart';

import 'package:meals_recipes/screens/categories_screen.dart';
import 'package:meals_recipes/screens/favorites_screen.dart';
import 'package:meals_recipes/widgets/main_drawer.dart';

class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
final List<Meal> favoriteMeals;

TabsScreen(this.favoriteMeals);

@override
State<TabsScreen> createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
List<Map<String, Object>> _pages;
int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

void _selectPage(int index) {
setState(() {
  _pages = [
    {'page': CategoriesScreen(), 'title': 'Categories'},
    {
      'page': FavoritesScreen(widget.favoriteMeals),
      'title': 'Your Favorites'
    }
  ];
  _selectedPageIndex = index;
  super.initState();
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title'] as String),
  ),
  drawer: MainDrawer(),
  body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: _selectPage,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.category), label: 'Categories'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.star), label: 'Favorites'),
    ],
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
    currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
    //type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
  ),
);
}
}
```

I have removed 'final' before that error line, but still have an error.
Please assist me.
I also added 'late' before it but still have an error.

Comment: Why do you call `super.initState();` inside a method that is not `initState`?

Comment: my bad! just removed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make _pages variable nullable by adding question mark like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>>? _pages;
```

Or if you don't want to make it nullable then you have to initialize it with the empty list like this

```
List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [];
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. thanks a lot